# Loop through two arrays while checking if both are are empty or not onClick of a button

Tags: android, performance, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I am stuck with something that might be trivial to many but it has become a problem for me.
Basically I am trying to loop thru two string arrays one of which has a static size and another which has variable size and may also be 0.

So my goal is to loop thru both of them while iterating through the first array and getting the values of the second array with the value of the first and loop completely through the second array.
However if the second array is empty I want to increase the index of the first array and query for the second array and go on till the first array and it's inner arrays are completely iterated.

Sounds easy but I am having a tough time writing something that works.

My code :

```
var array1 : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList() // static value say 10
        var array2 : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList() // may vary
        var array1index = 0
        var array2index = 0
        array1 = getArray1Value()
        button.setOnClickListener {
            if(array1index<array1.size){
                array2 = getByArray1Value(array1[array1index])
                if(array2.isEmpty()){
                  //increase array1 index
                    if(array1index<array1.size){
                    array1index+=1
                        array2 = getByArray1Value(array1[array1index])
                          //  ....... ?
                    }else{
                        over()
                    }
                }else{

                    if(array2index<array2.size){
                        array2index+=1
                    }else{
                        over()

                    }
                }

            }else{

                over()
            }
```

I think it is getting more complicated than it is supposed to....please help.

Comment: For sure here `array1index<=array1.size` is one problem. If `array1index == array1size` and you make `array1index+=1` then `array2 = getByArray1Value(array1[array1index])` will give you `IndexOutOfBound exception` where size is 10 and index is 10

Comment: ok..I see what else do I need to change? can you help me with a complete answer

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
private void doStuff() {
        if(array1index<array1.size){
            array2 = getByArray1Value(array1[array1index])
            if(array2.isEmpty()){

                    array1index+=1
                    doStuff();

            }else{

                if(array2index<array2.size){
                    array2index+=1
                }else{
                    over()

                }
            }

        }else{

            over()
        }
    }
```

Hope this is what you are trying to achieve

Comment: thanks SkypeDogg I found an answer This is new for me and I made it too big in my head lol

Comment: I did something same myself but you can see that  `array2 = getByArray1Value(array1[array1index])` is being called on every click

Comment: I couldn't imagine what is the purpose of that code, so it was hard for me to invent anything.

Comment: I just need to do what I explained in the question but I figured that showing a dialogue cut would down the complexity to none. Yes I never mentioned using dialogues and all being a possibility so I'm sorry for that

Comment: I was thinking about the questions and answers thing. I haven't get the purpose.

Comment: it is for a quiz like app

Comment: Yeah, now I know ;p

Answer (score 0):

If any newbie gets confused with something like this here is the answer:

```
val array1 : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList() // static value say 10 items
    var array2 : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList() // may vary
    var array1index = 0
    var array2index = 0
    array1 = getArray1Value()
    array2 = getByArray1Value(array1[array1index])
    button.setOnClickListener {
        if(array1index<array1.size){
            mLog.i(TAG,"number of questions : ${array2.size}")
            if(array2index<array2.size){
                mLog.i(TAG,"1 activity index $array1index question index $array2index ")
                array2index+=1
            }else{
                MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context).setTitle("Questions over")
                    .setMessage("ok thicha")
                    .setPositiveButton("ok"){
                            dialogInterface, i ->
                        dialogInterface.dismiss()
                        array2index =0
                        array1index+=1
                        if(array1index<array1.size){
                            array2 = getByArray1Value(array1[array1index])
                        }
                        button.callOnClick()
                    }.create().show()
            }

        }else{

            over()
        }

    }
```